# Spring ActiveMQ Connection Error Handling in a Loop

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

Part of my application requires a constant loop to check our ActiveMQ Messaging queue for "work".  I have setup this using a dedicated thread that starts after Spring initializes everything, so I have all my DI items I need.  The thread handles everything in a `while(true)` loop for now to just keep looking for messages.

I am setting up a single ActiveMQConnectionFactory and injecting it.  Using that AMQCF, in the loop I create a new `Connection`, setup a `Session` from the connection, set a `Destination`, and finally look at a `MessageConsumer` to `receive(5000)`.  If that detects a Message, I handle it and everything is fine.

My issue is connectivity issues between my application and the broker.  If the connection dies (AMQ goes down, etc) then an Exception is thrown and everything just kinda blows up.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dequeue(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:492)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:650)
at [AMQThreadClass]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
... 1 more
```

When my connection factory is setup I use a location containing a failover `jms.location=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?reconnectDelayExponent=2.0&useExponentialBackOff=true&initialReconnectDelay=30&maxReconnectAttempts=0` which I thought would work.  I think there is something else maybe missing, either from the loop or how I am handling the idea of Connect/Session/Destination/Consumer loop.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the proper way to safely handle connection issues which are bound to happen?

Comment: I have not worked with ActiveMQ, so I can't help you there, but I get really scared when you say you have `while(true)` in your code. If a spring bean needs to start threads, connect to sockets, then you should probably  implement SmartLifecyle, spring will automatically invoke start and stop when the context is refreshed and closed.  Typically you have a `private volatile boolean shutdown` which you set to true after the thread successfully starts, in stop you set `shutdown=false`, and inside your thread you have `while(!shuitown)`.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek I have seen a lot of `while(!shutdown)` style loops to handle the exiting.  That is something next on the plate of things todo :)  One step at a time.  Thanks for the advice on `SmartLifecycle`, I'll def. check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems having the reconnect string in the URI is very helpful.  This helps try and keep the connection alive.  I ended up using a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and `MessageListenerAdapter` in Spring with a `TaskExecutor` to handle the "watching" of the queue.  This makes it monitored with Spring and eliminated the need of a higher thread to handle the looping over the queue.

A needed step was making sure this was set to `autoStartup(false)`.  If the queue is down when Spring tries to initialize the Bean it will just wait and wait and never start.  To handle starting the connection (which initiates the monitoring set in place), I added a Startup Housekeeper kind of thread that `implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` for Spring.  This way on application start, after Beans are initialized and everything is "stable", I can then try and call the `ListenerContainer` to start up.

Starting the container up was moved into its own thread so it could be done asynchronously from the app and not block if the connection wasn't ready.  This allows the app to start just fine (queue up or down) and then connect when it can, adding in a Listener to handle any messages coming in.

No nasty while loop needed :)